# PHP Mailto isn't sending variables

Tags: php, mailto

I have trouble with sending emails on my website.

Here is a code:

```
$to  = 'xx@xx.com' . ', ';
$to .= 'yy@xx.com';
$subject = 'Potwierdzenie zakupu.';
$message = '$_POST[dostawa]';



$headers =
'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
'From: xx@xx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: xx@xx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When I put text in my message it's sending text but if I put some variables it's sending `$_POST[dostawa]` I can print this variables before and after this code with echo.

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
$message = '$_POST[dostawa]';
```

into

```
$message = $_POST['dostawa'];
```

Comment: Ups... Thank you so much  : )

Comment: @Kolobianka please mark tick on my answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score -1):

Since it is in single quote php consider it as string
Recommend you to please put it into double quote

```
$message = "$_POST[dostawa]";
```

Comment: Dont Just Down vote the answer. Specify the reason for that.